# Como recuperar o valores usando sortable! do data de uma li e a posição atual do

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, sortable

Estou tentando fazer a mudança dos (li) desse sistema que chamei de PRONTUARIOS, apenas arrastando de uma (ul) atual para outra que chamei de CAIXA, estou tentando recuperar o valor do id do prontuario (li) e a caixa atual que o usuário deixou o prontuario caso tenha mudado para uma nova caixa (ul). se alguem puder me ajudar, preciso recuperar o valor desses ids e atualiza no banco de dados!

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $("ul").sortable({
            delay: 150,
            connectWith: ".parent",
            cursor: 'move',
            stop: function() {
                var caixaAtual = new Array();
                var prontuario = '';
                $('li .prontuario').each(function() {
                    //caixaAtual = $("data-id").html();
                    //prontuario = $("data-id").val(this);

                });
                console.log(prontuario);
                //updateOrder(prontuario,caixaAtual);
            }
        });
         function updateOrder(id,caixa) {
            $.ajax({
                url:"<?php //DIRPAGE.LINK; ?>documentos/alterar_segundo_volume",
                type:'post',
                data:{id:id,caixa:caixa},
                success:function(data){
                    toastr.success('Alterado com sucesso.');
                }
            })
        }
    });
```

```html
<div class="container mx-auto mt-3 mb-5 text-center">
              <h4 class="col-12 text-center mx-auto">LISTAGEM SEGUNDO VOLUME</h4>
                               CAIXA N° 01                  <ul id="c_01" class="col-12 parent mt-0 mb-2 ui-sortable">
                                                <li id="239" data-id="239" class="col-12 mx-auto prontuario ui-sortable-handle">
                               <table class="table table-hover table-sm mb-0 ">
                                   <tbody><tr class="row col-12 mx-auto text-center">
                                    <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1</td>
                                    <td class="col-5 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-left">ADRIANO ALVES DE ALMEIDA</td>
                                    <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">617.598-8</td>
                                    <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1</td>
                                    <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1257101/2020</td>
                                    <td class="d-print-none col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"><a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="http://10.14.101.160/cimic/?url=documentos/excluir_segundo_volume/239" title="APAGAR"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
                               </tr>
                               </tbody></table>
                            </li>
                                                    <li id="247" data-id="247" class="col-12 mx-auto prontuario ui-sortable-handle" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
                               <table class="table table-hover table-sm mb-0 ">
                                   <tbody><tr class="row col-12 mx-auto text-center">
                                    <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">5</td>
                                    <td class="col-5 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-left">ALEX JORGE MELO DA SILVA</td>
                                    <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">664.041-1</td>
                                    <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1</td>
                                    <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1251911/2020</td>
                                    <td class="d-print-none col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"><a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="http://10.14.101.160/cimic/?url=documentos/excluir_segundo_volume/247" title="APAGAR"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
                               </tr>
                               </tbody></table>
                            </li><li id="241" data-id="241" class="col-12 mx-auto prontuario ui-sortable-handle">
                               <table class="table table-hover table-sm mb-0 ">
                                   <tbody><tr class="row col-12 mx-auto text-center">
                                    <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">2</td>
                                    <td class="col-5 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-left">ALEF DA SILVA OLIVEIRA</td>
                                    <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1.199.560-2</td>
                                    <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1</td>
                                    <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"></td>
                                    <td class="d-print-none col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"><a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="http://10.14.101.160/cimic/?url=documentos/excluir_segundo_volume/241" title="APAGAR"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
                               </tr>
                               </tbody></table>
                            </li>
                                                    <li id="240" data-id="240" class="col-12 mx-auto prontuario ui-sortable-handle">
                               <table class="table table-hover table-sm mb-0 ">
                                   <tbody><tr class="row col-12 mx-auto text-center">
                                    <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">3</td>
                                    <td class="col-5 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-left">ALEX ALVES CERQUEIRA</td>
                                    <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">340.704-6</td>
                                    <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1</td>
                                    <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1809667/2020</td>
                                    <td class="d-print-none col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"><a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="http://10.14.101.160/cimic/?url=documentos/excluir_segundo_volume/240" title="APAGAR"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
                               </tr>
                               </tbody></table>
                            </li>
                                                    
                                                    
                                                    <li id="248" data-id="248" class="col-12 mx-auto prontuario ui-sortable-handle">
                               <table class="table table-hover table-sm mb-0 ">
                                   <tbody><tr class="row col-12 mx-auto text-center">
                                    <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">6</td>
                                    <td class="col-5 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-left">ALEX XAVIER PIAUI</td>
                                    <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">771.513-9</td>
                                    <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1</td>
                                    <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1243357/2020</td>
                                    <td class="d-print-none col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"><a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="http://10.14.101.160/cimic/?url=documentos/excluir_segundo_volume/248" title="APAGAR"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
                               </tr>
                               </tbody></table>
                            </li>
                                                    <li id="249" data-id="249" class="col-12 mx-auto prontuario ui-sortable-handle">
                               <table class="table table-hover table-sm mb-0 ">
                                   <tbody><tr class="row col-12 mx-auto text-center">
                                    <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">7</td>
                                    <td class="col-5 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-left">ALEXANDRE DE OLIVEIRA MEDEIROS</td>
                                    <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">893.604-9</td>
                                    <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1</td>
                                    <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1415815/2020</td>
                                    <td class="d-print-none col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"><a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="http://10.14.101.160/cimic/?url=documentos/excluir_segundo_volume/249" title="APAGAR"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
                               </tr>
                               </tbody></table>
                            </li><li id="246" data-id="246" class="col-12 mx-auto prontuario ui-sortable-handle" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
                               <table class="table table-hover table-sm mb-0 ">
                                   <tbody><tr class="row col-12 mx-auto text-center">
                                    <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">4</td>
                                    <td class="col-5 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-left">ALEX EDUARDO DE JESUS LOURENCO</td>
                                    <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">236.643-3</td>
                                    <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1</td>
                                    <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1392042/2020</td>
                                    <td class="d-print-none col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"><a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="http://10.14.101.160/cimic/?url=documentos/excluir_segundo_volume/246" title="APAGAR"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
                               </tr>
                               </tbody></table>
                            </li>
                                                    <li id="250" data-id="250" class="col-12 mx-auto prontuario ui-sortable-handle">
                               <table class="table table-hover table-sm mb-0 ">
                                   <tbody><tr class="row col-12 mx-auto text-center">
                                    <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">8</td>
                                    <td class="col-5 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-left">ALEXANDRE PEREIRA DA COSTA</td>
                                    <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">932.592-9</td>
                                    <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1</td>
                                    <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1532754/2020</td>
                                    <td class="d-print-none col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"><a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="http://10.14.101.160/cimic/?url=documentos/excluir_segundo_volume/250" title="APAGAR"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
                               </tr>
                               </tbody></table>
                            </li>
                                            </ul>
  
                                CAIXA N° 02                  <ul id="c_02" class="col-12 parent mt-0 mb-2 ui-sortable">
                                                <li id="242" data-id="242" class="col-12 mx-auto prontuario ui-sortable-handle">
                               <table class="table table-hover table-sm mb-0 ">
                                   <tbody><tr class="row col-12 mx-auto text-center">
                                    <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1</td>
                                    <td class="col-5 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-left">ALEXSANDRO HENRIQUE FRANCA CAMARGO DE MOURA</td>
                                    <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1.224.350-7</td>
                                    <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1</td>
                                    <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">2092453/2020</td>
                                    <td class="d-print-none col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"><a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="http://10.14.101.160/cimic/?url=documentos/excluir_segundo_volume/242" title="APAGAR"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
                               </tr>
                               </tbody></table>
                            </li>
                                                    <li id="251" data-id="251" class="col-12 mx-auto prontuario ui-sortable-handle">
                               <table class="table table-hover table-sm mb-0 ">
                                   <tbody><tr class="row col-12 mx-auto text-center">
                                    <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">2</td>
                                    <td class="col-5 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-left">AMAURI FERREIRA DA SILVA</td>
                                    <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">613.004-1</td>
                                    <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">3</td>
                                    <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1243426/2020</td>
                                    <td class="d-print-none col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"><a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="http://10.14.101.160/cimic/?url=documentos/excluir_segundo_volume/251" title="APAGAR"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
                               </tr>
                               </tbody></table>
                            </li>
                                                    <li id="prontuario" data-id="243" class="col-12 mx-auto prontuario ui-sortable-handle">
                               <table class="table table-hover table-sm mb-0 bg-warning">
                                   <tbody><tr class="row col-12 mx-auto text-center">
                                    <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">3</td>
                                    <td class="col-5 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-left">ANDERSON LIMA RIBEIRO GONCALVES - <span class="text-danger">(LIBERDADE)</span></td>
                                    <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1.164.179-2</td>
                                    <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1</td>
                                    <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"></td>
                                    <td class="d-print-none col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"><a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="http://10.14.101.160/cimic/?url=documentos/excluir_segundo_volume/243" title="APAGAR"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
                               </tr>
                               </tbody></table>
                            </li>
                                                        <li id="252" data-id="252" class="col-12 mx-auto prontuario ui-sortable-handle">
                               <table class="table table-hover table-sm mb-0 ">
                                   <tbody><tr class="row col-12 mx-auto text-center">
                                    <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">4</td>
                                    <td class="col-5 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-left">ANDERSON SOUZA VELOSO</td>
                                    <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">277.426-3</td>
                                    <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1</td>
                                    <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"></td>
                                    <td class="d-print-none col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"><a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="http://10.14.101.160/cimic/?url=documentos/excluir_segundo_volume/252" title="APAGAR"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
                               </tr>
                               </tbody></table>
                            </li>
                                                    <li id="244" data-id="244" class="col-12 mx-auto prontuario ui-sortable-handle">
                               <table class="table table-hover table-sm mb-0 ">
                                   <tbody><tr class="row col-12 mx-auto text-center">
                                    <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">5</td>
                                    <td class="col-5 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-left">ANDRE ALMEIDA</td>
                                    <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1.096.394-0</td>
                                    <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">2</td>
                                    <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"></td>
                                    <td class="d-print-none col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"><a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="http://10.14.101.160/cimic/?url=documentos/excluir_segundo_volume/244" title="APAGAR"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
                               </tr>
                               </tbody></table>
                            </li>
                                                    <li id="245" data-id="245" class="col-12 mx-auto prontuario ui-sortable-handle">
                               <table class="table table-hover table-sm mb-0 ">
                                   <tbody><tr class="row col-12 mx-auto text-center">
                                    <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">6</td>
                                    <td class="col-5 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-left">ANDRE LUIZ RODRIGUES</td>
                                    <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">465.133-7</td>
                                    <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1</td>
                                    <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">2213488/2020</td>
                                    <td class="d-print-none col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"><a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="http://10.14.101.160/cimic/?url=documentos/excluir_segundo_volume/245" title="APAGAR"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
                               </tr>
                               </tbody></table>
                            </li>
                                            </ul>
  
                                CAIXA N° 03                  <ul id="c_03" class="col-12 parent mt-0 mb-2 ui-sortable">
                                                <li id="253" data-id="253" class="col-12 mx-auto prontuario ui-sortable-handle">
                               <table class="table table-hover table-sm mb-0 ">
                                   <tbody><tr class="row col-12 mx-auto text-center">
                                    <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1</td>
                                    <td class="col-5 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-left">ANDREO LEONE FERREIRA LOBATO</td>
                                    <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">719.305-5</td>
                                    <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">2</td>
                                    <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1359268/2020</td>
                                    <td class="d-print-none col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"><a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="http://10.14.101.160/cimic/?url=documentos/excluir_segundo_volume/253" title="APAGAR"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
                               </tr>
                               </tbody></table>
                            </li>
                           <li id="254" data-id="254" class="col-12 mx-auto prontuario ui-sortable-handle">
                               <table class="table table-hover table-sm mb-0 ">
                                   <tbody><tr class="row col-12 mx-auto text-center">
                                    <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">2</td>
                                    <td class="col-5 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-left">AUGUSTO PEREIRA DA SILVA</td>
                                    <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1.094.345-4</td>
                                    <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1</td>
                                    <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1183605/2020</td>
                                    <td class="d-print-none col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"><a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="http://10.14.101.160/cimic/?url=documentos/excluir_segundo_volume/254" title="APAGAR"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
                               </tr>
                               </tbody></table>
                            </li>
</ul>      
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode ler a sequencia dos elementos `LI` e por num `input` e ler isso no `php`. Pode fazer isso antes de fazer o submit, ou cada vez que ordernar, mas ideia e passar por exemplo a sequencia "239,247....",

Para demonstrar, criei um `<input type="text">` para poder ver os valores, depois é só postar a página ou passar esse valor para o `php`, que pode fazer um split e ter todos os ids em sequência.

```js
$("ul").sortable({
   stop: function() {
        var ordem = "";
        
        $("li").each(function() {
            if (ordem == "") 
               ordem = $(this).data("id")
            else
               ordem += "," + $(this).data("id");
        });
        
        $("#lista-ordem").val(ordem);
   }
});
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul li {
    border: solid 1px #000;
    margin: 0 3px 3px 3px;
    padding: 0.4em;
    padding-left: 1.5em;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    height: 18px;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>
   Ordem: 
   <input type="text" id="lista-ordem" style="width: 100%" />
</p>

CAIXA N° 01
<ul id="c_01" class="col-12 parent mt-0 mb-2 ui-sortable">
   <li id="239" data-id="239" class="col-12 mx-auto prontuario ui-sortable-handle">
       <table class="table table-hover table-sm mb-0 ">
           <tbody><tr class="row col-12 mx-auto text-center">
            <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1</td>
            <td class="col-5 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-left">ADRIANO ALVES DE ALMEIDA</td>
            <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">617.598-8</td>
            <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1</td>
            <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1257101/2020</td>
            <td class="d-print-none col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"><a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="http://10.14.101.160/cimic/?url=documentos/excluir_segundo_volume/239" title="APAGAR"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
       </tr>
       </tbody></table>
    </li>
    <li id="247" data-id="247" class="col-12 mx-auto prontuario ui-sortable-handle" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
       <table class="table table-hover table-sm mb-0 ">
           <tbody><tr class="row col-12 mx-auto text-center">
            <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">5</td>
            <td class="col-5 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-left">ALEX JORGE MELO DA SILVA</td>
            <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">664.041-1</td>
            <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1</td>
            <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1251911/2020</td>
            <td class="d-print-none col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"><a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="http://10.14.101.160/cimic/?url=documentos/excluir_segundo_volume/247" title="APAGAR"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
       </tr>
       </tbody></table>
    </li><li id="241" data-id="241" class="col-12 mx-auto prontuario ui-sortable-handle">
       <table class="table table-hover table-sm mb-0 ">
           <tbody><tr class="row col-12 mx-auto text-center">
            <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">2</td>
            <td class="col-5 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-left">ALEF DA SILVA OLIVEIRA</td>
            <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1.199.560-2</td>
            <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1</td>
            <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"></td>
            <td class="d-print-none col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"><a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="http://10.14.101.160/cimic/?url=documentos/excluir_segundo_volume/241" title="APAGAR"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
       </tr>
       </tbody></table>
    </li>
                            <li id="240" data-id="240" class="col-12 mx-auto prontuario ui-sortable-handle">
       <table class="table table-hover table-sm mb-0 ">
           <tbody><tr class="row col-12 mx-auto text-center">
            <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">3</td>
            <td class="col-5 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-left">ALEX ALVES CERQUEIRA</td>
            <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">340.704-6</td>
            <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1</td>
            <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1809667/2020</td>
            <td class="d-print-none col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"><a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="http://10.14.101.160/cimic/?url=documentos/excluir_segundo_volume/240" title="APAGAR"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
       </tr>
       </tbody></table>
    </li>
                            
                            
    <li id="248" data-id="248" class="col-12 mx-auto prontuario ui-sortable-handle">
       <table class="table table-hover table-sm mb-0 ">
           <tbody><tr class="row col-12 mx-auto text-center">
            <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">6</td>
            <td class="col-5 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-left">ALEX XAVIER PIAUI</td>
            <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">771.513-9</td>
            <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1</td>
            <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1243357/2020</td>
            <td class="d-print-none col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"><a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="http://10.14.101.160/cimic/?url=documentos/excluir_segundo_volume/248" title="APAGAR"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
       </tr>
       </tbody></table>
    </li>
                            <li id="249" data-id="249" class="col-12 mx-auto prontuario ui-sortable-handle">
       <table class="table table-hover table-sm mb-0 ">
           <tbody><tr class="row col-12 mx-auto text-center">
            <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">7</td>
            <td class="col-5 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-left">ALEXANDRE DE OLIVEIRA MEDEIROS</td>
            <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">893.604-9</td>
            <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1</td>
            <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1415815/2020</td>
            <td class="d-print-none col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"><a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="http://10.14.101.160/cimic/?url=documentos/excluir_segundo_volume/249" title="APAGAR"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
       </tr>
       </tbody></table>
    </li><li id="246" data-id="246" class="col-12 mx-auto prontuario ui-sortable-handle" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
       <table class="table table-hover table-sm mb-0 ">
           <tbody><tr class="row col-12 mx-auto text-center">
            <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">4</td>
            <td class="col-5 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-left">ALEX EDUARDO DE JESUS LOURENCO</td>
            <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">236.643-3</td>
            <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1</td>
            <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1392042/2020</td>
            <td class="d-print-none col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"><a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="http://10.14.101.160/cimic/?url=documentos/excluir_segundo_volume/246" title="APAGAR"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
       </tr>
       </tbody></table>
    </li>
                            <li id="250" data-id="250" class="col-12 mx-auto prontuario ui-sortable-handle">
       <table class="table table-hover table-sm mb-0 ">
           <tbody><tr class="row col-12 mx-auto text-center">
            <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">8</td>
            <td class="col-5 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-left">ALEXANDRE PEREIRA DA COSTA</td>
            <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">932.592-9</td>
            <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1</td>
            <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1532754/2020</td>
            <td class="d-print-none col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"><a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="http://10.14.101.160/cimic/?url=documentos/excluir_segundo_volume/250" title="APAGAR"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
       </tr>
       </tbody></table>
    </li>
                    </ul>

        CAIXA N° 02
    <ul id="c_02" class="col-12 parent mt-0 mb-2 ui-sortable">
                        <li id="242" data-id="242" class="col-12 mx-auto prontuario ui-sortable-handle">
       <table class="table table-hover table-sm mb-0 ">
           <tbody><tr class="row col-12 mx-auto text-center">
            <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1</td>
            <td class="col-5 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-left">ALEXSANDRO HENRIQUE FRANCA CAMARGO DE MOURA</td>
            <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1.224.350-7</td>
            <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1</td>
            <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">2092453/2020</td>
            <td class="d-print-none col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"><a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="http://10.14.101.160/cimic/?url=documentos/excluir_segundo_volume/242" title="APAGAR"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
       </tr>
       </tbody></table>
    </li>
                            <li id="251" data-id="251" class="col-12 mx-auto prontuario ui-sortable-handle">
       <table class="table table-hover table-sm mb-0 ">
           <tbody><tr class="row col-12 mx-auto text-center">
            <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">2</td>
            <td class="col-5 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-left">AMAURI FERREIRA DA SILVA</td>
            <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">613.004-1</td>
            <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">3</td>
            <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1243426/2020</td>
            <td class="d-print-none col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"><a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="http://10.14.101.160/cimic/?url=documentos/excluir_segundo_volume/251" title="APAGAR"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
       </tr>
       </tbody></table>
    </li>
                            <li id="prontuario" data-id="243" class="col-12 mx-auto prontuario ui-sortable-handle">
       <table class="table table-hover table-sm mb-0 bg-warning">
           <tbody><tr class="row col-12 mx-auto text-center">
            <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">3</td>
            <td class="col-5 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-left">ANDERSON LIMA RIBEIRO GONCALVES - <span class="text-danger">(LIBERDADE)</span></td>
            <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1.164.179-2</td>
            <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1</td>
            <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"></td>
            <td class="d-print-none col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"><a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="http://10.14.101.160/cimic/?url=documentos/excluir_segundo_volume/243" title="APAGAR"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
       </tr>
       </tbody></table>
    </li>
                                <li id="252" data-id="252" class="col-12 mx-auto prontuario ui-sortable-handle">
       <table class="table table-hover table-sm mb-0 ">
           <tbody><tr class="row col-12 mx-auto text-center">
            <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">4</td>
            <td class="col-5 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-left">ANDERSON SOUZA VELOSO</td>
            <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">277.426-3</td>
            <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1</td>
            <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"></td>
            <td class="d-print-none col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"><a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="http://10.14.101.160/cimic/?url=documentos/excluir_segundo_volume/252" title="APAGAR"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
       </tr>
       </tbody></table>
    </li>
                            <li id="244" data-id="244" class="col-12 mx-auto prontuario ui-sortable-handle">
       <table class="table table-hover table-sm mb-0 ">
           <tbody><tr class="row col-12 mx-auto text-center">
            <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">5</td>
            <td class="col-5 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-left">ANDRE ALMEIDA</td>
            <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1.096.394-0</td>
            <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">2</td>
            <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"></td>
            <td class="d-print-none col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"><a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="http://10.14.101.160/cimic/?url=documentos/excluir_segundo_volume/244" title="APAGAR"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
       </tr>
       </tbody></table>
    </li>
                            <li id="245" data-id="245" class="col-12 mx-auto prontuario ui-sortable-handle">
       <table class="table table-hover table-sm mb-0 ">
           <tbody><tr class="row col-12 mx-auto text-center">
            <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">6</td>
            <td class="col-5 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-left">ANDRE LUIZ RODRIGUES</td>
            <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">465.133-7</td>
            <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1</td>
            <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">2213488/2020</td>
            <td class="d-print-none col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"><a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="http://10.14.101.160/cimic/?url=documentos/excluir_segundo_volume/245" title="APAGAR"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
       </tr>
       </tbody></table>
    </li>
                    </ul>

        CAIXA N° 03                  <ul id="c_03" class="col-12 parent mt-0 mb-2 ui-sortable">
                        <li id="253" data-id="253" class="col-12 mx-auto prontuario ui-sortable-handle">
       <table class="table table-hover table-sm mb-0 ">
           <tbody><tr class="row col-12 mx-auto text-center">
            <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1</td>
            <td class="col-5 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-left">ANDREO LEONE FERREIRA LOBATO</td>
            <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">719.305-5</td>
            <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">2</td>
            <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1359268/2020</td>
            <td class="d-print-none col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"><a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="http://10.14.101.160/cimic/?url=documentos/excluir_segundo_volume/253" title="APAGAR"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
       </tr>
       </tbody></table>
    </li>
   <li id="254" data-id="254" class="col-12 mx-auto prontuario ui-sortable-handle">
       <table class="table table-hover table-sm mb-0 ">
           <tbody><tr class="row col-12 mx-auto text-center">
            <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">2</td>
            <td class="col-5 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-left">AUGUSTO PEREIRA DA SILVA</td>
            <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1.094.345-4</td>
            <td class="col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1</td>
            <td class="col-2 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center">1183605/2020</td>
            <td class="d-print-none col-1 align-middle mx-auto p-0 text-center"><a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="http://10.14.101.160/cimic/?url=documentos/excluir_segundo_volume/254" title="APAGAR"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
       </tr>
       </tbody></table>
    </li>
</ul>
```